# Netflix encoding system - MAPLE

Tags: software-recommendation, encoding, transcoding

I understand that Netflix does all their encoding in AWS using EC2.  They have a custom encoding software called MAPLE that chunks all source video into 2-3 second chunks and encodes in multiple codec and formats across many EC2 instances in parallel.

Netflix is known to open source their software, however I am not finding that MAPLE has.  Does anyone know if an alternative / similar encoding/packaging scheme is available in open source?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You might consider using AWS' transcoding service.  I'm not sure if it's as parallelized as MAPLE, but it is very fast.  Perhaps it's fast enough as-is for your use case?

Answer (score 1):

MediaEncodingCluster is an Enterprise Class, Video Cluster Environment with a Plattform Independent Client - Server Architecture for distributed video/audio converting/encoding tool over a grid Computing Network Design. more on http://docs.codergrid.de

Note: I haven't personally tried this yet. I'll update with some benchmarks when I do.

Sources:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/bripper/

http://codergrid.de/trac/